# Add custom post type as submenu

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I have a custom post type called '**Movies**' that I want to add under WooCommerce menu after "Extensions" as you can see below:

[image]

The WooCommerce page URL is `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-admin`

I tried:

```php
register_post_type( 'movie', array(
    'show_in_menu' => 'admin.php?page=wc-admin'
) );
```

but that didn't work. I am able to set Movies under Tools, Settings, Post, etc everywhere else, just not inside WooCommerce/custom options page. Any ideas why?